# Formulas change following Save As

Tags: excel

Is it possible to stop Excel from modifying formulas when doing `Save As`?

The original formulas was:

`=IF('MyWorkSheet'!J12>0,'MyWorkSheet'!J12,"")`

Following `Save As`, this was the formula in the new file `original2.xlsx`:

`=IF('C:\path\to\[original.xlsx]MyWorkSheet'!J12>0,'C:\path\to\[original.xlsx]MyWorkSheet'!J12,"")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: No.
The 'original formula' does not refers to a currently open workbook. Whenever you close one of the files in your workspace, Excel MUST preserve its capacity to recalc when you reopen. So it has to save the path to the external file.
However you can [modify the source of your external references](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/open-or-change-source-workbooks-of-external-references-links-ae3e687c-97ae-4d9b-b684-8756a5301253).

> Open the destination workbook.
>   On the Data tab, in the Connections group, click Edit Links.
>   In the Edit Links dialog box, click the source workbook that you want to change.
>   Click Change Source.

Comment: There are no entries in that specific tab. In the workbook in question, the formulas were pointing to worksheets contained in the current workbook.

Comment: I just noticed, if from Windows Explorer I copy the file and rename it, the formulas stay intact.